# Как подключить CSS к django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, django-template

Помогите пожалуйста! Не могу понять, почему не подключается css в html на django. При запуске получаю только html, без css, в логе пишет:

```
[13/Jul/2021 15:08:19] "GET /products/smartwatch/UMIDIGI-Uwatch-3S-black/? HTTP/1.1" 200 9268
Not Found: /products/static/mainapp/css/style.css
[13/Jul/2021 15:08:20] "GET /static/mainapp/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1790
Not Found: /products/static/mainapp/media/imgonline-com-ua-Replace-color-tc87FXAM0b.jpg
[13/Jul/2021 15:08:20] "GET /products/static/mainapp/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2518
Not Found: /products/static/mainapp/media/thumb_agm-x2_agm.org_22.jpg
[13/Jul/2021 15:08:20] "GET /products/static/mainapp/media/imgonline-com-ua-Replace-color-tc87FXAM0b.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2632
[13/Jul/2021 15:08:20] "GET /products/static/mainapp/media/thumb_agm-x2_agm.org_22.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2578
```

HTML-код:

```
    {% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <link type="text/css" href="{% static 'mainapp/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg " style="background-color: black;">
                <div class="container">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 head_list  "   >
                            <li class="nav-item ">
                              <a class="nav-link active  " aria-current="page" href="#">Головна</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link  " href="main-page.html">Доставка та оплата</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ">
                              <a class="nav-link " href="garanti.html"> Гарантія/ Повернення </a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link  " href="#" >Контакти</a>
                            </li>
                         </ul>


                    </div>
            </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py

```
[!["""
Django settings for shop project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os.path
from pathlib import Path


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = \[\]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = \[
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainapp',
\]

MIDDLEWARE = \[
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
\]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'shop.urls'

TEMPLATES = \[
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': \[\],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': \[
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            \],
        },
    },
\]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'shop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"))
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = \[
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
\]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (css, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_dev'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
)
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'][1]][1]
```

Структура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `urls.py` проверьте что раздаете статику через `static(...)` а если на проде - проверьте что раздаете через nginx  или что у вас там

Comment: команду `manage.py collectstatic` выполняли? Выполните и проверьте, что создалась папка `static` в корне проекта. Именно из нее идет раздача.

Comment: @RomanKonoval не помогло

Comment: Т.е. у вас есть в корне папка `static`, а в ней те файлы, которые не находятся, скажем `mainapp/css/style.css`?

Comment: Еще важный вопрос. Как вы запускаете приложение?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Да

Comment: @RomanKonoval python manage.py runserver